# Mocha: Run set of test cases on multiple JSON object in an array. Need Correct approach

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have an array which contains more than one JSON objects, so to run the set of the test cases on each JSON object I've to put "foreach" inside each test case. I am sure this is not the right way to do it because when my test case numbers will increase it will be inefficient. I've looked at a couple of other questions but all of them unsuccessful in this case. Can someone please suggest me the right way to approach this.

```
 let responseData;    
    before((done)=>
        {
            promiseResp.then((data) => {
                responseData =data;
                done();
            }, (err) => {
                console.log('promiseResp.err', err);
                process.exit(1);
            })

        })
        describe('AC 1', ()=>
        {
                        it('Test1', ()=>
                        {
                            responseData.forEach(responseData=>
                            {
                                expect(responseData.abc).not.toBe(responseData.abc);
                            })

                        });

                        it('Test 2', ()=>
                        {
                            responseData.forEach(responseData=>
                            {
                                expect(responseData.abc).not.toBe(responseData.abc);
                            })

                        });

                        it('Test 3', ()=>
                        {
                            responseData.forEach(responseData=>
                            {
                                expect(responseData.xyz).toMatch(/[*xyz]/);
                            })
                        });

                        it('Test 4', ()=>
                        {
                            responseData.forEach(responseData=>
                            {
                                for (let i = 0; i < responseData.pqr.length; ++i)
                                {
                                    expect(responseData.pqr).toBeFalsy();
                                }
                            })
                        });

            after(()=>
            {
                process.exit(0);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for clarity sake, the way you have it broken out is just fine. The point of tests isn't to optimize them for performance but to single out specific test cases and make it very clear to understand when they fail.

You can reduce iterations through your `responseData` if you do all of your checks in a single iteration, but understand you'd be sacrificing clarity into what is failing because you'd now be testing for 2 conditions in a single pass rather than 1.

Comment: Exactly that is my concern, suppose if I limit data in "responseData" only up to 2 JSON objects. While running "Test 1" the first dataset passed the test case but 2nd failed but in the whole that test case is failed and the result shows something like this "Test 1 failed" but it never shows which dataset/JSON object caused the failer.

Comment: Right. Like I said the way you have it is optimized for clarity and that's a good thing. The only time you'd care about the performance of your tests is if it's gating deployments and increasing deployment time because the test cases take so long to run. Your ```responseData``` test object will only ever contain enough objects to test all cases thoroughly so it won't ever be a problem.